# iOS 5.1.1, html5 images blurry

Tags: image, html, ios5, css, mobile-safari

I'm working on a hyrbid iPhone app, with most of the interface being done in HTML5 and CSS3. Recently, it seems that since the ios 5.1 update specifically, the images in the app have become really fuzzy/blurry, as if they are being stretched out. They are all `div`s with the `background-image` property set, and `background-size` set to 'cover'.

I also have this line in the html index file, but I do not see how it should effect anything

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320"/>
```

Here's an example of how poorly an image looks. This image is sized at around 2em x 2em, which, if I'm not wrong, should come out to around 32px by 32px with a 16px font-size.

[image: blurred image in app]

The original image:

[image: original]

As you can see, the original has a pretty large resolution, and there shouldn't be any stretched in the app when it's 32px by 32px.

Please, this is very frustrating, so any help is greatly appreciated. Like I said, it didn't do this before, it seems to have just come up since the latest iOS 5.1 update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was the culprit

```
*
{
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

I originally had these in because sometimes my CSS3 animations would cause the screen to flicker, and this fixed that. Well, it seemed to be trading one bag of problems for another, because removing these two styles made everything clear & crisp again.

I did a little bit more looking, and it appears

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

is rumored to fix the flickering without adding the blur.

Comment: I know this is old. But... Dear Future Web Developer, every element on your site doesn't need to be hardware accelerated. You would probably be better served picking and choosing only the items that really need it. Your browser will be happier, your phone will be nicer, and little annoying things like this will be avoided. Thank you, Eric.

Comment: That may be true now, but on older iPhones, animations looked terrible without hardware acceleration if you were trying to get a native look and feel.

Comment: Oh its still true in quite a few situations. I'm just talking about the use of the wildcard selector `*` . Thats going to cause every element to try and become hardware accelerated not just the animated ones.

Answer (score 1):

For the retina display, you may want to include an indication of the higher resolution images. Such as:

```
background-image: url(your-image@2x.png);
```

Comment: Right, but all that an @2x image is is just a higher resolution than the original, right? If so, the image that I'm currently using is already of pretty high resolution -- and the screenshot I took is from the 5.1 simulator using the non-retina option.

Comment: @Marklar Are you setting the image's size by em's or px?

Comment: I'm setting it by em. It's about 2em by 2em

Comment: @marklar Maybe try without that meta tag, and with px instead of em.

Comment: No luck. Thanks so much for trying to help, though.